# random curve with fixed size between two endpoints

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I have read this post in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268106/generating-random-curves-with-fixed-length-and-endpoint-distance
The main task is drawing a continuous curve between two fixed points that has also a fixed length.

I wondered how can I implement it in python?
I was looking for creating it in pytorch, but opencv and scikit image also works for me.
I was unable to find even a relatively close implementation anywhere.
Do you have any suggestion what function from what package can make it work?

Comment: What about `cubic bezier curves`? There you have 4 points. 2 end points and 2 control points. If you could calculate the length of the curve you maybe can change the control points to have right length.

Comment: Thank you @MSH, that's a great idea; however, I want to let the curve be as random as possible, so if it wants to make a loop on its path.

Comment: What happens if you put the second control before the first one?

Comment: See thee example here: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/html5-canvas-2nd/9781449335847/ch05s03s05.html you could also use a spline with a random number of control points

Comment: It is possible to mimic what I want by putting together multiple curves together.